# Iteration order is defined of for..in loops in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs, for-in-loop

I know ECMAScript specification. In ECMA-262 3, section 12.6.4 wrote

> The mechanics of enumerating the properties ... is implementation dependent.

Also some documents said

> A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order.

And I know in some older chrome is also in random order.

But now I found almost all the browsers returned keys in order added. For Example

```
var o = {};
o["c"]=1;
o["b"]=2;
o["a"]=3;

for(var x in o )
    console.log(x); // Must return "c b a"
```

And When I read ReactJS source, I found the implementation is basing on it in some functions (for example `_updateChildren`, if for-in does not return key in order added, it would render wrong)

My question is "is it a standard returning keys in order added when for-in a object"? How can I trust it?

Comment: That's a side effect of the red-black trees used to implement objects under the hood. There is no guarantee we will keep using these in the future. Things can and *will* change.

Comment: In ES2015 that becomes more adopted from release to release - there is an item that explicitly defines the consistent order of enumeration. For string keys it's the order of their creation.

Comment: It's de facto in ES5, which became de jure in ES2015.